# When will the LIR's run out of the IPv4 addresses?

Tags: ipv6

"The Asia Pacific Network Information Centre, the RIR responsible for assigning IP addresses to the region, announced the release of its last available batch of IPv4 addresses on **15 April**."

http://www.eweekeurope.co.uk/news/ipv6-traffic-remains-miniscule-27099

But when will all the LIR's (-> e.g.: ISP's) in the world run out of the IPv4 addresses?

When will the IPv4 addresses truly run out?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, we have run out since all the IP addresses have been assigned to ISP's. Of course, due to re-allocation at their level, we have not yet really run out, and it is very hard to say exactly when that will happen.

Here is a good article on that subject. You can read the whole thing, but I linked specifically to the section on regional exhaustion since you asked specifically about your region.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion#Regional_exhaustion